# Laravel 5.1 : CSRF protection and echoing submitted form values

Tags: jquery, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to echo the entered form values using jQuery, but getting `POST http://localhost:8000/settings/generalsettings/changedata 500 (Internal Server Error)` error when I click submit. I'm using Laravel 5.1.

What's missing in my code?

Here's my routes.php

```
Route::post('settings/generalsettings/changedata', 'UserSettingsController@changeData');
```

UserSettingsController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UserSettingsController extends Controller
{

        public function changeData()
    {
        $variable = Input::post('name99');

        print_r($variable);
    }
}
```

generalSettings.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=""/>
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</head>
<body>
    <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name">
    <input type="submit" id="sub">
    <div id="result"></div>
    <script src="/js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // set up jQuery with the CSRF token, or else post routes will fail
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });            // handlers
            $("#sub").click(function (y) {
                y.preventDefault();
                var user_name = $('#name').val();
                $.post(
                        "/settings/generalsettings/changedata",
                        {
                            name99: user_name
                        },
                        function (data) {
                            $('#result').hide().html(data).fadeIn(2000);
                        });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `use Input` at the top of my `UserSettingsController` class and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Add `use Input` at the top of your controller file

Try to use `get` instead of using `post` to receive ajax data in controller.

```
$variable = Input::get('name99');
```